# I want to validate the user input in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, input

I'm trying to validate different user inputs, and i want to inform them which input is null
i tried to show an alert dialog whenever the user hit the submit button while an input is null, but then i got an error and it didn't open the page saying i have to fill the information before i even open the page. However i tried a something else but unfortunately it didn't work ether this is what i did.

```
 TextFormField(
                    key: _formKey,
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null) {
                        return 'please write a review';
                      } else if (DATA == null) {
                        return 'please select a category';
                      } else if (image == null) {
                        return 'please add an image';
                      } else if (tag == null) {
                        return 'please select sub category';
                      } else if (_descriptionController.text == null) {
                        return 'please select a location';
                      } else
                        return null;
                    },
                    maxLines: 20,
                    maxLength: 200,
                    controller: _descriptionController2,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding:
                          EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 16.0),
                      hintText: "What do you think about the place?",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0)),
                    ),
                  ),
```

That's what i added to the button when it's pressed

```
onPressed: () {
          bool valid = validation();
          if (valid)
            addData(image!, DATA!, lat, lng, _descriptionController2.text,
                tag!, loggedInUser2!);
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
```

lastly this is the validation method

```
bool validation() {
final form = _formKey.currentState;
if (form!.validate()) {
  return true;
}
return false;
```

}

can any one help?

Comment: You should post the full error message

Answer (score 0):

The `validator(String? value)` in widget `TextFormField` should validate **ONLY** for its text value. Other fields like `Data`, `image`... should be handled in another place.

I'm also working on `validator` for `TextFormField` and I realize that we shouldn't check null. Because when you first time navigate to this screen, the `TextFormField` will immediately show red error message below and it could make user uncomfortable. You should check null only when user press "Save/Comment" button and show popup/snack bar if the text is null/empty.

Also I got some tricks that you may interest:

- Use extension (extension for `String?`) if you has some special cases can be used in future, like: valid email, valid password (8 character, special symbols)...
- Don't forget to use function `.trim()` to remove white space on textEditingController.

Answer (score -1):

i think is unnecessary for doing validation of DATA,image, etc for description field.
`TextFormField` will return String, it will always false when you do validation for DATA, image, etc.

just do like this:

```
Form(
  key:_formKey,
  child: Column(
    children:[
       TextFormField(
          validator: (String? value) {
            //  runType value is String? 
            //  which is it always false when you compare to image, or Data.
            if (value == null) {
              return 'please write a description';
            else
              return null;
            },
          controller: _descriptionController2,
        ),
```

then if you want to do validation for other data, i think you can make it manually.

```
if (DATA== null) {
  //do something 
}
...etc
```